# SQL Calculate accumulated total but filter out certain rows

Tags: mysql, windowing

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Transition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 01/Jan/09 | 1 |
| 23 | 08/Jan/09 | 1 |
| 12 | 02/Feb/09 | 1 |
| 77 | 14/Feb/09 | 0 |
| 39 | 20/Feb/09 | 1 |
| 33 | 02/Mar/09 | 1 |

I would like a query that returns a running total of the "somedate" column, BUT I want to ignore the transitions from where it goes from "0" to "1" or "0" to "0". (IE: the time between ID: 77 and ID: 39 should not be calculated in the running total). The other transitions ("1" to "0", "1" to "1") should counted as usual.

I want my table to look something like this:

| ID | Date | Running_Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 01/Jan/09 | 0 |
| 23 | 08/Jan/09 | timeDiff(Jan1, Jan8) |
| 12 | 02/Feb/09 | timeDiff(Jan1, Jan8) + timediff(Jan8, Feb2) |
| 77 | 14/Feb/09 | timeDiff(Jan1, Jan8) + timediff(Jan8, Feb2) + timeDiff(Feb2, Feb14) |
| 39 | 20/Feb/09 | timeDiff(Jan1, Jan8) + timediff(Jan8, Feb2) + timeDiff(Feb2, Feb14) + 0 |
| 33 | 02/Mar/09 | timeDiff(Jan1, Jan8) + timediff(Jan8, Feb2) + timeDiff(Feb2, Feb14) + 0 + timeDiff(Feb20, Mar2) |

Something like that. I know how to calculate the accumulated cost, but I was wondering if there's any way to get the accumulated cost but also filter it out based on "transitions".

I've tried looking online and on other window functions, but not sure how to incoporate the fact of "looking" at future rows and comparing to initial row with window function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I rather like @LajosArpad solution but here is one way of doing it with [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) -

```
SELECT *, SUM(`Diff`) OVER (ORDER BY `Date` ASC)
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        IF (
            LAG(`Transition`) OVER (ORDER BY `Date` ASC) = 1,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, LAG(`Date`) OVER (ORDER BY `Date` ASC), `Date`),
            0
        ) AS `Diff`
    FROM temp
) t;
```

This assumes that `Date` contains valid dates (`'2009-01-01'`) and not the strings (`'01/Jan/09'`) you have in your example. I have used [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) instead of [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: Nice approach! If the dates are not actual dates, then `STR_TO_DATE` https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/ can be used to convert it, but I agree we shouldn't overcomplicate the code. If the asker faces ordering issues, then this function will prove to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN previous.Transition = 1 THEN TIMEDIFF(current.`Date`, previous.`Date)
        ELSE 0
    END
)
FROM yourtable current
JOIN yourtable previous
ON previous.`Date` < current.`Date`
LEFT JOIN yourtable inbetween
ON previous.Date < inbetween.Date AND inbetween.Date < current.Date
WHERE inbetween.ID IS NULL
```

The above adds the difference between `current` and `previous` to a grand total (in terms of `TIMEDIFF`) where `previous.Transition` is 1 and there is no item between `previous` and `current`.

Comment: Thanks! What is "inbetween" here and "yourtable" in your answer

The name of the first table I have in my post is called "temp". That is the only table that I am using here.

Comment: @Spicysauce `yourtable` is `temp` then, while `inbetween` is an alias to a record for it whose existence is excluded by the query. We find `current` and `previous` where `previous` is earlier than `current` and we search for any record `inbetween`. If no such `inbetween` record is found, then `previous` and `current` are consecutive records.

Comment: When I run this command but I replace "yourtable" with "temp", I get a SQL error that "no table inbetween exists"

Comment: @Spicysauce yup, it was a typo on my part. Adjusted my answer, you can test again.

Comment: @Spicysauce a `yourtable` was missing just before `inbetween`.

Comment: Thanks, apologies, when I run this code again, it still gives me "Unknown column 'inbetween' in 'on clause'" error

Comment: Honestly, simpler question I want to ask is I just want the total time, IE:
timeDiff(Jan1, Jan8) + timediff(Jan8, Feb2) + timeDiff(Feb2, Feb14) + 0 + timeDiff(Feb20, Mar2), I don't need an entire table or anything, just that particular value

Comment: @Spicysauce can you edit your question and paste the exact query you tested with?

Comment: @Spicysauce I guess you didn't notice the `yourtable` after the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I think you need to change the join condition for `inbetween` to `ON previous.Date < inbetween.Date AND inbetween.Date < current.Date`

Comment: @nnichols thanks for pointing it out, you were absolutely correct. It was late and I was tired, thanks for suggesting the fix. I have prepended a `NOT` for better readability, but it's equivalent to your suggestion, so the idea for fix definitely came from you. Thanks!

Comment: Not totally equivalent to @nnichols I believe, because BETWEEN is inclusive, right?

Comment: Yes, the anti-join needs to exclude the bounds and not be negated, I think.

Comment: @nnichols yup, you are correct.